# View displays nothing after creating it with VARCHAR condition

Tags: mysql

I tried to create view in MYSQL with condition of `VARCHAR` gender, but it shows nothing. I also tried to create view of staff with the same city but it shows nothing too. But when I set `INTEGER` condition to other view, it works perfectly.

Image 1:
[image: stuffgender table]
Image 2:
[image]

```
CREATE VIEW stuffgender AS SELECT * 
FROM nyv_individ 
WHERE gender LIKE 'M';

CREATE VIEW Non_Inog_rab AS SELECT * FROM Non_individ WHERE mesto_git LIKE ‘%Архангельск%’;
```

None of these are working, just showing nothing, but it should.

Comment: "Not working" doesn't help. What data is this running on? What does the equivalent `SELECT` produce?

Comment: @tadman
https://ibb.co/JnZ2jbB
https://ibb.co/vsRRtBx

Comment: @tadman it just shows nothing

Comment: What is your integer condition? `gender = 1`

Comment: @deej  it's `CREATE VIEW nyv_rab_vozr 
AS SELECT * 
FROM nyv_individ 
WHERE vozrast between 20 and 22;
`

Comment: Probably has to do with the Cyrillic characters.
Put the prefix N before your string literals and see if it works. exp: `WHERE gender LIKE N'M'`
You should probably also use nvarchar instead of varchar.

Comment: Are you sure it is a latin M and not a cyrillic М (unicode U+041C)? Maybe try to select "other", this looks latin (or Ж, where you know its cyrillic). For the other view: if it is a copy&paste: your quotes do not seem to be correct, they have to be single normal quotes (`'`)

Comment: If you have freedom to change type, I would say go with enum for gender column. Enum internally uses tinyint datatype and you can go up to 255 options. I suspect character set issue like @Solarflare does.